# Reactstrap installation into existing project unclear to me

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, reactstrap

I have an existing project and am really starting to jump into the frontend. Just have placeholders basically currently to make sure the backend and frontend were talking.

I want to use `reactstrap`, but the directions aren't entirely clear to me so was looking for clarification. I have been skipping over the `create-react-app` section as I am not using that.

I am just at the  **Adding Bootstrap** section. It says:

> `npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0`

Right off this says:

```
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I was under the impression `jquery` and `react` were mutually exclusive, so do I really need to do this?

> `npm install --save reactstrap@next react@^16.0.0 react-dom@^16.0.0`

This installs fine.

Then it says:

> Import Bootstrap CSS in the src/index.js file:
>
> `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';`

I guess suggesting to just download the CSS file and read it into the entry point. Is `reactstrap` dependent on this configuration to work properly?

Can't I just read in Bootstrap v4 via CDN into the `index.html` of the SPA? Would `reactstrap` still work properly?

Is one more preferable than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore jQuery warning since reactstrap uses only css part of bootstrap.

Yes. CDN would work provided that you included link for bootstrap 4.0.